# 4D polytope analogues of the icosahedron/Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction relationship?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, modular-forms, convex-polytopes

The formula for the j-function which employs polynomial invariants of the *icosahedron*,

$$j(\tau)=-\frac{(r^{20} - 228r^{15} + 494r^{10} + 228r^5 + 1)^3}{r^5(r^{10} + 11r^5 - 1)^5}$$

where,

$$r^{-1}-r=\frac{\eta{(\tau/5)}}{\eta{(5\tau)}}+1$$

and $r = r(\tau)$ is the *Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction* and the modular form *Dedekind eta function* $\eta{(\tau)}$ is well-known.

***Question***: Is there a similar relationship between any of the six regular 4D polytopes and some known modular form?

***P.S.*** Somebody asked me this question.

Comment: I believe the tag 'gt.geometric-topology' should be replaced with the tag 'mg.metric-geometry'. You may also want to add the tag 'convex-polytopes'.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I would guess not. The connection between the level-5 j-function and the icosahedron is ultimately due to the fact that $PSL(2, 5)$ is isomorphic to the group of rotations of the icosahedron. I don't think any of the symmetry groups of the 4-polytopes are of the form $PSL(2, q)$. The 5-cell does have symmetry group $S_5$ and so contains $PSL(2, 5)$ but this is just the group of the icosahedron anyway.